# PHP Array foreach only outputs when more than 1 value is found

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I need to loop through an array which can have one, or more values (some attributes in this case). My problem is that it outputs something only when more than one value is found. If there's only one value in the array, it doesn't output anything at all.

I would like to also output the one and only value found, or more if any more. I tried inserting break , but then it would only stop at the first value found, an stop looking for other values... How can I fix this ?

```
<?php 
    foreach ($_product->getAttributeText('attribute') as $attribute): 
        echo $attribute.' ';
    endforeach ;
?>
```

Comment: use break if found !!

Comment: Please show us the output of `$_product->getAttributeText('attribute')` when only one attribute is found.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: it is the other way around. He wants to output all found data.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty "I tried inserting break , but then it would only stop at the first value found"

Comment: its possible that `$_product->getAttributeText('attribute')` isn't an array on which `foreach` can be applied when there is only one value

Comment: try `echo is_array($_product->getAttributeText('attribute'))` to see if it is always an `array`. you can apply `foreach` only if it is an `array` , otherwise it would give you a warning

Comment: What does `getAttributeText` do? Since `foreach` is pretty straight forward that leaves only this function.

Comment: @anurupr: yes thanks , this must have been the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that what's happening is what @anurupr has mentioned in the comments. Do you have your warnings suppressed?

Try the following:

```
<?php
$mAttributeText = $_product->getAttributeText('attribute');
if (is_array($mAttributeText)) {
    foreach ($mAttributeText as $sAttribute) {
        echo $sAttribute . ' ';
    }
} else {
    echo $mAttributeText;
}
```

Comment: Yes anurupr was right. Because it is working using 'is_array' as you shown in your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAttributeText` method may not return an array if only one attribute is found (a `foreach` on an array with only one element should be working)

Moreover, that will not answered your question but maybe help you : have you look the function `implode` ?

```
echo implode(" ", $_product->getAttributeText('attribute'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that

```
$_product->getAttributeText('attribute')
```

returns an array.

Weird syntax maybe? Look at this example and try like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_loop_foreach